# ImageIO.getReaderMIMETypes() returning null on Linux running tomcat, works fine locally

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jai

Running my spring app in eclipse and tomcat7 locally everything works fine, but when I deploy it to tomcat 7 running on our linux server, the app fails to start because I'm registering a

```
<bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.BufferedImageHttpMessageConverter">
```

And it calls:

```
ImageIO.getReaderMIMETypes()
```

which appears to be returning null, because it all fails when it gets to here:

```
public static MediaType parseMediaType(String mediaType) {
    Assert.hasLength(mediaType, "'mediaType' must not be empty");
```

I thought maybe it was an issue with running headless=true, but I changed my local server to that and it still worked. I thought maybe it had something to do with JAI jars, but the jre that being used by Tomcat on the server does indeed have the jai jars in jre/lib/ext

Comment: So the problem appears to be that ImageIO.getReaderMimeTypes() returns a list with one blank entry at the beginning. I can either extend one of the spring classes involved, or figure out why there is a blank entry being returned to begin with?

Comment: I switched to  ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter and it works, I'll still accept an answer if someone can post a way to either override the spring classes involved, or unregister the blank mimetype

Comment: I also have this problem on Linux where ImageIO.getReaderMimeTypes() returns a list with one blank entry. Have you found a solution since your post ?